# Python under uWSGI creates files and dirs with wrong permissions

Tags: python, permissions, nginx, filesystems, uwsgi

I'm a newbie in Python developing.

I write a small Python web app that creates some files and directories. When I run it in command line everything is ok. But under uWSGI all new files get -rw-rw-rw- mode, and directories - drwxrwxrwx instead of -rw-rw-r-- and drwxrwxr-x respectively.

uWSGI configuration is default for Ubuntu, nothing special. uWSGI app ini file is simply like this:

```
[uwsgi]
plugins=python
```

nginx config is like that:

```
server {

        listen 8080;

        access_log /path/to/logs/access.log;
        error_log /path/to/logs/error.log;

        location / {
                uwsgi_pass unix:/var/run/uwsgi/app/myapp/socket;
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_param UWSGI_PYHOME /path/to/myapp/.env/;
                uwsgi_param UWSGI_CHDIR /path/to/myapp/;
                uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT myapp;
        }

}
```

I guess problem is in insufficient uWSGI configuration, but I don't know what I have to do.

Comment: how are you starting your uwsgi process? Depending on that, you can set a umask to specify permissions on created files/directories

Comment: Thanks Thomas! The problem was solved simply by specifying option umask=002 in ini config. But in official documentation option umask described as "Set UNIX socket umask." http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#umask Weird...

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by uWSGI's default umask of 000 which leaves all bits in place - which means a default of 666 for files or 777 for directories.

You can chance this by setting the [`umask`](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#umask) option on your uWSGI config file to the bits that should be removed. For example, to get 644/755, you'd use an umask of 022 which cleary the write flag for group/other (777-022 = 755, 666-022 = 644)